# Debugging in Eclipse (using JRebel): Source not found

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, cdi, jrebel

This might be the x-th question with this title, but the other ones and their answers did not help me. Please pay attention to the tags.

If I set a breakpoint to a line of code in my current project and the debugger hits it, it will display an error `Source not found.` and offer me to `Edit Source Lookup Path...`.

E.g. when I set the breakpoint to a line in my `StartBean.java` the stack frame will be called

`StartBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.processGeocodingData(ActionEvent) line: not available`

and the title of the windows saying `Source not found` is also not called `StartBean.java` as it should but also starts with `StartBean$Proxy...`.

Seems like that it indeed not the file I want to look into. I already modified the `Source Lookup Path`: Deleted some "Default" and added `Java-Project` -> `MyProject` but it did not help.

I also activated all "default" step filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "JRebel Eclipse Debugger Plug-In" causes this behaviour when a breakpoint is set to a line declaring a method.

**Solution:**
Set your breakpoints to a line *inside* the method.